# Dart web app not accessing MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, dart, dart-async

I am trying to write a simple single-page web app in Dart using the "observatory" package. What it should do is display all the data in the "Name" collection, retrieve the user's input, add lastly that input to both the on-screen list and the collection. The input gets added to the unordered list, but that's all that happens. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here is my Dart code:

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:objectory/objectory_browser.dart';

class Name extends PersistentObject {
  String get collectionName => "Name";

  String get first => getProperty("first");
  set first(String value) => setProperty("first", value);

  String get last => getProperty("last");
  set last(String value) => setProperty("last", value);
}

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost/dosdart1';

registerClasses() {
  objectory.registerClass(Name, () => new Name(), () => new List<Name>());
}

void main() {
  objectory = new ObjectoryWebsocketBrowserImpl(uri, registerClasses, false);
  loadNames();
  querySelector('#output').text = 'Your Dart app is running.';
  var btn = querySelector('#btn');
  btn.onClick.listen(addName);
}

Future display(name) {
  var completer = new Completer();
  name.fetchLinks().then((__) {
    var ul = querySelector('#names');
    var li = new LIElement()
    ..appendText("${name.first} ${name.last}");
    ul.append(li);
    completer.complete(true);
  });
  return completer.future;
}

loadNames() {
  objectory.initDomainModel().then((_) {
    return objectory[Name].find();
  }).then((names){
    return Future.wait(names.map((name) => display(name)));
  }).then((_) {
    objectory.close();
  });
}

addName(MouseEvent e) {
  var name = new Name();
  InputElement firstElement = querySelector('#first');
  InputElement lastElement = querySelector('#last');
  name.first = firstElement.value;
  name.last = lastElement.value;
  objectory.initDomainModel().then((_){
    name.save();
    return;
  }).then((_) {
    objectory.close();
  });
  display(name);
}
```

And here is my web page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
  Copyright (c) 2015, <your name>. All rights reserved. Use of this source code
  is governed by a BSD-style license that can be found in the LICENSE file.
-->

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="scaffolded-by" content="https://github.com/google/stagehand">
    <title>hybrid_dart</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script async src="main.dart" type="application/dart"></script>
    <script async src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="output"></div>
  <p><label for="first">First name:</label><input type="text" id="first" name="first"></p>
  <p><label for="last">Last name:</label><input type="text" name="last" id="last"></p>
  <p><button id="btn" name="btn" title="Insert">Insert</button></p>
  <ul id="names">
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You need to chain futures to ensure they are executed in order. I don't see for every call if it returns a `Future` or a sync value therefore I might miss here and there (I added `/* await */` where in doubt).
The new `async` / `await` feature makes it much easier to work with async code therefore I changed all your `then(...)` to `async`/`await`.

```
main() async {
  objectory = new ObjectoryWebsocketBrowserImpl(uri, registerClasses, false);
  await loadNames();
  querySelector('#output').text = 'Your Dart app is running.';
  var btn = querySelector('#btn');
  btn.onClick.listen(addName);
}

Future display(name) async {
  await fetchLinks();
  var ul = querySelector('#names');
  var li = new LIElement()
    ..appendText("${name.first} ${name.last}");
  ul.append(li);
}

Future loadNames() async {
  await objectory.initDomainModel();
  var names = await objectory[Name].find();
  await Future.wait(names.map((name) => display(name)));
  /* await */ objectory.close();
}

Future addName(MouseEvent e) async {
  var name = new Name();
  InputElement firstElement = querySelector('#first');
  InputElement lastElement = querySelector('#last');
  name.first = firstElement.value;
  name.last = lastElement.value;
  await objectory.initDomainModel();
  name.save();
  /* await */ objectory.close();
  await display(name);
}
```

Without `async`/`await` it should be like

```
void main() {
  objectory = new ObjectoryWebsocketBrowserImpl(uri, registerClasses, false);
  loadNames().then((_) {
    querySelector('#output').text = 'Your Dart app is running.';
    var btn = querySelector('#btn');
    btn.onClick.listen(addName);
  });
}

Future display(name) {
  return name.fetchLinks().then((__) {
    var ul = querySelector('#names');
    var li = new LIElement()
    ..appendText("${name.first} ${name.last}");
    ul.append(li);
  });
}

Future loadNames() {
  return objectory.initDomainModel().then((_) {
    return objectory[Name].find();
  }).then((names){
    return Future.wait(names.map((name) => display(name)));
  }).then((_) {
    /* return */ objectory.close();
  });
}

Future addName(MouseEvent e) {
  var name = new Name();
  InputElement firstElement = querySelector('#first');
  InputElement lastElement = querySelector('#last');
  name.first = firstElement.value;
  name.last = lastElement.value;
  return objectory.initDomainModel().then((_){
    name.save(); 
    return;
    // if "name.save();" returns a Future this should be
    // return name.save();
  }).then((_) {
    /* return */ objectory.close();
  }).then((_) {
    return display(name);
  });
}
```

Comment: Putting async on main is not a good idea. I tried both of your code ideas and neither one worked. I need someone familiar with the "objectory" package and MongoDB.

Comment: Why should `async` on main be a bad idea? "Neither one worked"  isn't very expressive.

Comment: Well, the neither one added to the database or added the input to the unordered list..

Comment: So, why do you think `async` on `main()` is a bad thing? I'm sure it's just fine. Just ensure you don't have `void` as return type. You had several obvious async bugs in your code and there are probably more. It's hard to see from just looking at your code fragment. I suggest you add some print statements to see live what's going on to figure out where it misbehaves. With more concrete information I might be able to provide further guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the riddle using forcemvc and server-side MongoDB:

```
library serverweb2;

// add code to names() to retrieve all the names
// change names.html accordingly

import "package:forcemvc/force_mvc.dart";
import "package:objectory/objectory_console.dart";
import 'dart:async';

main(List<String> args) {
  objectory = new ObjectoryDirectConnectionImpl('mongodb://127.0.0.1/serverweb2',
      registerClasses, false);
  var app = new WebApplication();
  app.start();
//  print('Hello world!');
}

@Controller
class Controllers {

  @RequestMapping(value: "/", method: RequestMethod.GET)
  String index(req, Model model) {
    return "index";
  }

  @RequestMapping(value: "/names", method: RequestMethod.POST)
   Future names(ForceRequest req, Model model) {
    objectory.initDomainModel().then((_) {
      req.getPostParams().then((params) {
        var first = params['first'] as String;
        var last = params['last'] as String;
        var name = new Name()
          ..firstName = first
          ..lastName = last;
        name.save();
        return objectory[Name].find();
      }).then((names) {
        model.addAttribute('names', names);
        return;
      }).then((_){
        req.async("names");
        objectory.close();
      });
    });
    return req.asyncFuture;
  }
}


class Name extends PersistentObject {
  String get collectionName => "Name";
  String get firstName => getProperty("first_name");
  set firstName(String value) {
    setProperty("first_name", value);
  }
  String get lastName => getProperty('last_name');
  set lastName(String value) {
    setProperty('last_name', value);
  }

  @override
  String toString() => "$firstName $lastName";
}

registerClasses() {
  objectory.registerClass(Name, () => new Name(), () => new List<Name>());
```